# Pandas assign error - keyword can't be an expression

Tags: pandas

I can assign new columns to a DataFrame as follows:

```
df_so = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({0: 'jane',
 1: 'baz',
 2: 'baz',
 3: 'dave',
 4: 'dave',
 5: 'dave'},orient='index',columns=["name"])


df_so.assign(val="bar")
```

| index | name | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | jane | bar |
| 1 | baz | bar |
| 2 | baz | bar |
| 3 | dave | bar |
| 4 | dave | bar |
| 5 | dave | bar |

**Issue**

If I try assign with an f string I get the following error

```
an_other = "another"
df_so.assign(f"{an_other}_val"="bar")

SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

Is there any workaround while still using assign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, with dictionary unpacking:

```py
>>> an_other = "another"
>>> df_so.assign(**{f"{an_other}_val": "bar"})

   name another_val
0  jane         bar
1   baz         bar
2   baz         bar
3  dave         bar
4  dave         bar
5  dave         bar
```

Key-value pairs of the dictionary will be passed to `.assign`; the contents of the dictionary will have been already established at that point.